# Getting all combinations from a list using itertools

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I am working on a problem with project Euler and I need to get all combinations of adding int elements in a list,

```
from itertools import combinations
evenAbs = [12, 18, 20, 24, 30,36]
evenCombs =  sorted(([i+j for i,j in combinations(evenAbs, 2)]))
```

my problem is that I need the combinations to include 12+12 18+18 etc..
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement([1,2,3], 2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: thanks a million, my answer was a a couple of hundred off the correct answer, having not realized until after many hours that combinations did not add values to themselves, the combinations_with_replacement did exactly what I needed!